# jQuery/JavaScript - Allow CTRL + Click to open link in new tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way in jQuery or JavaScript to enable the user to CTRL + Click a link to open a link in a new tab like `<a href="">example</a>` element?

Here is an example of what I am talking about:-

```
jQuery('#some-link').bind('click', function() {
   window.location = 'http://someurl.com';
});
```

If you hold CTRL and click the 'some-link' element, it just opens the page within the current page when using the above code, any ideas on how do this?

Comment: Have a look .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript

Comment: You will probably also want to check for a ctrl key press I think

Comment: There are many keys that change the default behavior. You're better off using something like [`filter-altered-clicks`](https://github.com/bfred-it/filter-altered-clicks) to handle it for you.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Check to see if the `Ctrl` key is pressed, and open the link using `window.open`. The link may not open in a new tab though. See the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript).

```
jQuery('#some-link').bind('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   if (e.ctrlKey){
     window.open('http://someurl.com','_blank')
   }
});
```

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/endkxe37/)

Comment: `if (e.metaKey)` could be better approach, since `e.ctrlKey` will work on Windows environment not in Mac, while `metaKey` will work in both

Comment: @Max definitely appreciate trying to account for every device, but I couldn't actually get `e.metaKey` to work (at least on Windows), checking for either though seems to be working.

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone wants to disable page navigation on regular click, to make an ajax call or something, but still wants to keep the default ctrl+click and right-click and middle-click(mouse scroll button) , that is the way:

```js
$('#link').bind('click', function(e) {
  if (!e.ctrlKey && e.which != 2 && e.which != 3) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // some logic:
    $('#box').append('<br>').append($('<a>').html('not paging but doing something! Now try with CTRL'));
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="box">
  <a id="link" href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26823884/">this question</a>
</div>
```

JQuery [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.which/) says:

> event.which also normalizes button presses (mousedown and
>   mouseupevents), reporting 1 for left button, 2 for middle, and 3 for
>   right. Use event.which instead of event.button.

Answer (score 0):

On Macintosh keyboards, this is the ⌘ Command key. On Windows keyboards, this is the Windows key (⊞ Windows).

For more see this page:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/metaKey