# how to prevent javascript blocking of open new tab with ctrl+click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, browser

In chrome standart behavour for ctrl+click is open link in new tab.

But inline js `<a href="..." onclick="<some js>">` hinders to open in new tab with ctrl+click. It just opens link in same tab.

What is easiest way to provide a normal behavior by ctrl+click for this case?

Comment: Whats your actual intention? do you want the page open in new tab or ctrl + click then new tab?

Comment: I want to provide standart behavour on ctrl+click. So if any link with inline js will ctrl+click, it will open in new tab.

Comment: this is an answer using jQuery, but the basics are the same: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26823929/5269101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can be a little more specific on what you want to do exactly, I might be able to help you more.

I am not quite sure on what your asking. But to use **onclick** to open a new tab. You can use the example below.

```js
function tab(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  win.focus();
}
```

```html
<a onclick="tab('http://www.google.com');">New Tab</a>
```